# Bootstrap: file input field ignores clicks when used in modal dialog

Tags: javascript, events, file-upload, twitter-bootstrap

I have a little weird problem with Bootstrap and a file field:

For a project I'm implementing a simple upload dialog.

http://jsfiddle.net/RxxSv/4/

As soon as I add `data-toggle="modal"` to the modal container, the file input field stops reacting to clicks (and the browser won't show the file selection dialog).

I suspect this to be caused by Bootstrap's modal code/event handling. Somewhere the click event is getting lost, but I can't really figure it out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't really explain why but if you put all the attributes that are in the [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) (in the Live Demo), the input works correctly.

```
<div id="modal-upload" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" 
role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4TQvY/

Comment: Thanks for the hint. After doing a bit more research based on your answer, I found out that the `data-toggle="modal"` is not even supposed to be in the modal container. This should be on the button that toggles the modal instead. I have no idea how it ended up in the container, but it certainly was my fault. tl;dr: Remove the `data-toggle` attribute.

Comment: the data-toggle attribute was causing me fits as well, thanks badcat

Answer (score 0):

My comrade adviced to do it in another way:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" style="margin-left: 100px" id="prefix">Choose file</a><input type="file" id="file_source" style="position:absolute;z-index:2;top:0;left:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);opacity:0;background-color:transparent;color:transparent;">
```

Make separate a & input and then invoke click event

```
    jQuery("#prefix").click(function()
    {
        console.log("INSERT JSON");
        $("#file_source").click();
        return false;
    });
```